# SQL query to return salaries greater than average salary

Tags: sql-server

Consider a table `EMPLOYEE` with columns `empid`, `deptid` and `salary` to extract all employees who have salaries higher than the avg. of their department

I tried it two ways - 1st way is this:

```
Select empid, deptid, salary
From employee
Group by empid, deptid, salary
Having salary > (Select avg(salary) From employee)
```

This returned a correct output.

But

```
Select empid, deptid, salary, avg(salary) average
From employee
Group by empid, deptid, salary
Having salary > avg(salary)
```

returned no output as well as no error it was black output.

Software used is Microsoft SQL Server

I wanted to know why second output is not returning any output?

Comment: First needs to be dept average. Second, because the average of the same number can't be greater than itself.

Comment: I don't think the first one is correct -- isn't that the avg for all dept not just the one in question?

Answer (score 4):

The reason you get no results in your second query is because you are grouping by salary, therefore all salaries within that group will be the same, as such the average will be the same. So if the salary within a particular group is 50k, the average will be 50k, and 50k is not greater than 50k, it is equal.

I'd also assume that `empId` is your primary key, so grouping by this is (with no other joins) is almost always going to be pointless because by definition you have one row per group.

Your first query also isn't right, you would need to filter the subquery by department to ensure you were only comparing the average within that particular employees department, e.g.

```
Select empid,deptid,salary
From employee AS e
Group by empid,deptid,salary
Having salary>(Select avg(salary) FROM employee AS e2 WHERE e2.deptId = e.Deptid)
```

However, since you have moved the aggregate to the subquery, the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` are not necessary and this can be simplified to:

```
Select empid,deptid,salary
From employee AS e
Where salary>(Select avg(salary) FROM employee AS e2 WHERE e2.deptId = e.Deptid);
```

I would however be inclined to do this with a windowed function:

```
SELECT  e.EmpID, e.DeptId, e.Salary, e.DeptAvg
FROM    (   SELECT  e.EmpID, 
                    e.deptid, 
                    e.Salary,
                    DeptAvg = AVG(e.Salary) OVER(PARTITION BY e.deptid)
            FROM    employee AS e
        ) AS e
WHERE   e.Salary > e.DeptAvg;
```

Comment: thank you and yes my first query will not give dept wise out put but will give salary of employee > average salary of employee


tried this 

'''select  e.empid,d.deptid,e.Salary,d.deptavg
from Employee e join (Select deptid,avg(salary) as deptavg
from Employee
group by deptid) d on e.DeptID=d.DeptID
where e.salary>d.deptavg'''


and also got dept wise average

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the salary and avg by dept.

```
Select deptid, avg(salary) as dept_avg
From employee
Group by deptid
```

This gives you the ones above avg

Then you join back to find the ones you want.

```
select e.empid, e.deptid, e.salary
FROM emplyee e
JOIN (
  Select deptid, avg(salary) as dept_avg
  From employee
  Group by deptid
) sub on sub.deptid = e.deptid
WHERE e.salary < sub.dept_avg
```

Comment: No point grouping by and aggregating the same value, this will not get the right results

Comment: Now you have another problem: selecting an aggregated column. This needs either a correlated subquery or a window function, it cannot be done with normal aggregation

Comment: @Charlieface -- fixed again :)

Comment: _This gives you the salary and avg by dept._ No it does not. You include empid in the GROUP BY clause. This means you get a average per (empid, deptid) - which is most likely logical nonsense. You make the same mistake in the second query as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you for each row SQL calculates AVG for particular record so each AVG(salary) will be equal to salary of particular employee. Here you looking for two operations, first find average salary of individual department and second is for particular department find list of employees which have greater than avg salary of that department

```
;WITH cteavgsalary AS 
(SELECT deptid,
           AVG(salary) AS avgsalary
    FROM employee
    GROUP BY deptid)

SELECT e.empid,       e.deptid,       e.salary,       cte.avgsalary
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN cteavgsalary cte ON e.deptid = cte.deptid
AND e.salary > cte.avgsalary
```

Here cteavgsalary  will be table which will hold record of department wise average salary and then you making inner join of that CTE on particular department Id

It will provide you exact output you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using cte and window function using the `avg` function:

```sql
with cte_highest
as

(
select firstname,dept,salary,avg(salary) over (partition by dept) as avg_sal
from employee
)
select firstname,dept,salary,avg_sal from cte_highest
where salary > avg_sal;
```